# Update button not working

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms

I am trying to update my database via a windows form button in C#. It isn't showing any errors when I run the code that I am about to show but it doesn't change the data in the database or data grid.

```
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection NewCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\ASPNET\cd\cdcwk2\cddatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE cdstock set cd_title='" + cdtext.Text + "', artist='" + artisttext.Text + "',genre='" + genretext.Text + "', rating=" + ratingtext.Text + ", cd_discription='" + distext.Text + "' where cd_id =" + idtext.Text + ";", NewCon);
    MessageBox.Show("UPDATE cdstock  set cd_title='" + cdtext.Text + "', artist='" + artisttext.Text + "',genre='" + genretext.Text + "', rating='" + ratingtext.Text + "', cd_discription='" + distext.Text + "' where cd_id ='" + idtext.Text + "'");

    NewCon.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    NewCon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Has Now Been UPDATED!!");

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to manually run displayed query?

Comment: Have you tyyed running the generated commang using SQL Management studio or other sql clients?

Comment: What does `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns?

Comment: Please Check the number of rows affected coming from following line, int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); You can run SQL Profiler and see the command coming to the server and debug into it.

Comment: What does the first `MessageBos.Show("UPDATE...` show?

Comment: type of cd_id is int or varchar?

Comment: @sharafjaffri cd_id is a int .

Comment: @rajesh Subramanian 1 is being affected when i change title.

Comment: Then update is working correctly.

Comment: Use paramterized queries. *Use parameterized queries!* **Use parameterized queries!!** - how often do we have to repeat this?

Comment: Maybe you should try using a paramaterized query?

Comment: Expanding on Thorsten's posted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

For everyone's sake, don't use string concatenation to build a SQL command: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found the solution and it working fine now, thank you for your time. Solution is below.

```
             String NewCon = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\ASPNET\cd\cdcwk2\cddatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(NewCon);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

         cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE cdstock set cd_title='" + cdtext.Text + "', artist='" + artisttext.Text + "',genre='" + genretext.Text + "', cd_discription='" + distext.Text + "', rating=" + ratingtext.Text + " where cd_id = " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
         cmd.Connection = con;
         cmd.Connection.Open();

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         cmd.Connection.Close();
```

cddatabaseDataSet3.GetChanges();
 this.cdstockTableAdapter.Fill(this.cddatabaseDataSet3.cdstock);

```
        MessageBox.Show("Record Has Now Been UPDATED!!");
```